# Cannot convert from const char[] to std:string *

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

In a visual c++ cli project file i created the following class (c++ type) . 
not able to declere a string or char type suitable for name variable.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std ;

class MyClass 
{
public :
int x;
int y;
string * name;

void foo() { name = "S.O.S" ;}
};
```

P.s . type casting err

Comment: It's `#include <string>` not `#include <string.h>`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to make the following changes:

```
#include <string> // not <string.h>

class MyClass
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    string name; // not string*
};
```

EDIT:

To address comments by [eliz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191407/eliz), a small example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    string name;

    string foo()
    {
        name = "OK";
        return name;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass m;

    // Will print "OK" to standard output.
    std::cout << "m.foo()=" << m.foo() << "\n";

    // Will print "1" to standard output as strings match.
    std::cout << ("OK" == m.foo()) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: alternatively he could use `name = new string("S.O.S"), but that would be quite dangerous if there isn't a copy constructor

Comment: @Petesh, I was going to suggest that, but decided using `string` was simpler.

Comment: @hmjd how can i check your answer string foo() {name = "OK"; return name ;}

Comment: If you mean check it works correctly, then just compare the return value: `if ("OK" == m.foo())`, where `m` is an instance of `MyClass`.

Comment: @hmjd how can i check your answer. string foo() {name = "OK"; return name ;}

Comment: I just commented on this @eliz ?

Answer (score 2):

If `name` is of type `string *`, then you must call one of the string constructors.

```
name = new string("S.O.S");
```

And don't forget to release your string in the destructor (~MyClass())!

Comment: Copy constructor and assignment operator would also need implemented as the default versions would be insufficient.

Comment: Yes, the big four is necessary for every class with dynamic data.